# Controller and directive variable's scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to AngularJS. I've started learning it from basics and began doing the simplest examples and the custom ones. Recently I've found some strange behavior of AngularJS.

I have the following code snippet:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
 .controller('aCtrl', function($scope){})
 .controller('bCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.message = 'Hello!';
 })
 .directive('b',function()
 {
  return {
   controller: 'bCtrl',
  };
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="aCtrl">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    <div b>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in this example, we define our module - `test`, one directive `b` and two controllers: `aCtrl` and `bCtrl`, and bind `bCtrl` to `b`. In the `bCtrl`'s `$scope` service we define variable `message` and assign string `Hello!` to it. In the `html` code you can see `body` element with `ng-app="test"` and two `div` elements inside it: one with `aCtrl` controller, and the other one with `b` directive.

The code above produces me

```
Hello!
```

when it, as far as I understand, should produce nothing, since there is no variable `message` defined in the `$scope` of `aCtrl` controller.

Is this normal behavior or maybe I am missing something about AngularJS controllers and directives?

Comment: aCtrl  produce nothing your Output  Hello! comes from  directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directives are shared among scopes depends on where and how are you using it. There are different kind of scopes.:- shared, inherited, isolated. I am giving you the link to which what i am referring to. [Behavior of custom directives](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/11/understanding-scopes-in-angularjs-custom-directives.aspx)